# Django model delete method not overriding

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm currently working on a Django blog app where I have a `Post` connecting to a `Category`. The `Category` has both `name` and `times_used` fields. `times_used` will be incremented by 1 after a Post is created and I have achieved this overriding the `save()` method on the `Post` model. I'm trying to override the `delete()` method to decrement the current post's category by 1 but it's not actually reaching the overridden `delete()` method it seems, because the category still has the incremented value even after the post got deleted. See my code below...

**model.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    times_used = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # This increments this category by 1 then saves the post - Works well!
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.category.times_used += 1
        self.category.save()

        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # This decrements this category by 1 then deletes the post - Which is not working...
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.category.times_used -= 1
        self.category.save()

        super(Post, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show how you are deleting `Post`?

Comment: I was simply deleting from admin site. However, I read about `Django signals` and worked a way to achieved what I wanted. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Yes I was asking that because how you delete matters a lot when it comes to overriding `delete` ;)

Comment: Based on my understanding as long as we want to delete objects in bulk using a QuerySet the override method won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read about Django signals just now and have accomplished what I wanted to. According to the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods)... the delete() method doesn't get called when we override it to delete objects in bulk using a QuerySet. So it's best to use a signal to get these types of job done.

In my `models.py` I've pass the `Post` as an argument to a function which I have a created in `signals.py`

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ....

delete_post_signal(Post)
```

Within my `signals.py` I have the following code...

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete


def delete_post_signal(Post):

    @receiver(pre_delete, sender=Post)
    def decrement_category_usage(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.category.times_used -= 1
        instance.category.save()
```

This worked for me perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pre_delete signal like this

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Post)
def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.category.times_used -= 1
    instance.category.save()
```

Comment: I've tried this method at first but have gotten an error... `InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'blog.templatetags.custom_tags': cannot import name 'Post' fr
om partially initialized module 'blog.models'` so I had to figured it out another way. See my answer.

Comment: It happens due to circular import. You can solve this by importing your model this way `from blog import models` and then call your model in code `blog.models.Post` or use get_model function [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model) this way 
`from django.apps import apps`
`Post = apps.get_model("blog.Post")`

Comment: Please note, I'm currently not working with the `ready()` method in my `apps.py`. This is what I have set up to work on each call to delete a post `delete_post_signal(Post)`.